# Generate 12 months for each field in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset as follows

```
Particulars "TotalBud"  "TotalTar"
Staff Cost   374.58      320.45 
Staff Expenses   15.81   13.53 
Supply Costs     56.35   48.21 
Labour costs     22.41   19.19
```

I want to generate a dataframe that looks like :

```
"Particulars"   "TotalBud"  "TotalBud_Apr"  "TotalBud_May"  "TotalBud_Jun"  "TotalBud_Mar"  "TotalTar"  "TotalTar_Apr"  "TotalTar_May"  "TotalTar_Feb"  "TotalTar_Mar"
Staff Cost   374.58      31.21   2.60    0.22    0.02    320.45      266.33      212.20      158.07  03.95 
Staff Expenses   15.81   1.32    0.11    0.01    0.00    13.53   11.25   8.97    6.69    4.41 
Supply Costs     56.35   4.70    0.39    0.03    0.00    48.21   40.07   31.93   23.79   15.65 
Labour costs     22.41   1.87    0.16    0.01    0.00    19.19   15.96   12.74   9.51    6.29
```

I want Columns from April to March for each existing columns and they must be x/12 where x is the original value of that column. If my excel file contains new columns, the code should be able to iterate and generate month fields for them as well

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am unable to formulate anything yet as i am novice in python

Comment: for f in glob.glob("Raw/*.xlsx"):
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    df1 = xls.parse(sheet_name=0)
   
    df1['Total_Bud_Apr'] = df1['Total\nBud']/12
    print(df1.head())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

data = pd.read_excel('Budget.xlsx',sheet_name=0)
data.fillna(0,inplace=True)

new_colums = data.columns
new_colums = new_colums.insert(1,'Month')

master_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_colums)

month_list = ['APR-20','MAY-20','JUN-20','JUL-20','AUG-20','SEP-20','OCT-20','NOV-20','DEC-20','JAN-21','FEB-21','MAR-21']

def rowTranformation(row):
    global master_data
    temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_colums)
    for i in range(12):
        val = []
        val.append(row[new_colums[0]])
        val.append(month_list[i])
        for j in new_colums[2:]:
            val.append(round(row[j]/12,2))
        temp.loc[i] = val
    master_data = master_data.append(temp,ignore_index=True)


data.apply(lambda x: rowTranformation(x),axis=1)
master_data.to_excel('output.xlsx',sheet_name='MonthlyView',index=False)
```